# Login, Logout tracking using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to summarize the login, logout information of a user. If a user has one of the event types 1 or 3 both are considered as login event. If a user has 6,7 or 13 then it is considered as logout event.  Each time the user has this event type, I want to consider the first event that happens and calculate how long they were logged in.

Here is the sample Data:

```
    DECLARE @T AS TABLE
    (
                ID          INT,
                access_time datetime,
                EventId varchar(10),
                EventType varchar(25)
    )
        
insert into @T VALUES

(123,'2021-10-15 06:00:29', 1, 'Autheticated' ),
(123,'2021-10-15 06:00:39', 3, 'Loggedin' ),
(123,'2021-10-15 08:00:14', 6, 'Loggedout' ),
(123,'2021-10-15 13:00:39', 3, 'Loggedin' ),
(123,'2021-10-16 00:00:12', 6, 'Loggedout' ),
(123,'2021-10-16 00:00:39', 7, 'Timedout' ),
(123,'2021-10-16 00:15:40', 13, 'ApplicationClosed' ),
(123,'2021-10-17 04:32:16', 3, 'Loggedin' ),
(123,'2021-10-17 15:45:20', 7, 'Timedout' ),
(123,'2021-10-17 15:47:40', 13, 'ApplicationClosed' )

DECLARE @final AS TABLE
(
    ID          INT,
    Login_time datetime,
    Logout_time datetime 
)

insert into @final VALUES

(123,'2021-10-15 06:00:29', '2021-10-15 08:00:14'),
(123,'2021-10-15 13:00:39', '2021-10-16 00:00:12'),
(123,'2021-10-17 04:32:16', '2021-10-17 15:45:20')
        
select * from @final
```

I tried using the `lead` function and I am not getting the results as expected due to missing events for some days. How to get data in `@final` formatted without using the `lead` function?

Comment: The lead function i used is just pulling the value for the next row.

Comment: What are your desired results for the provided sample data?

Comment: `without using the lead function` Why can't you use `LEAD()` ? Are you using a older version of SQL Server that does not support it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a type of *gaps-and-islands* problem.**

There are a number of solutions, here is one

- Calculate starting points for each set of rows using `LAG`
- Using a running conditional count, calculate an ID for each of those groups
- Then simply group up using those IDs

```sql
WITH StartPoints AS (
    SELECT *,
      IsStart = CASE WHEN EventId IN (1,3) AND LAG(EventId, 1, -1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY access_time) NOT IN (1,3) THEN 1 END
    FROM @T
),
Groupings AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(IsStart) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY access_time)
    FROM StartPoints
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Login_time = MIN(access_time),
  Logout_time = MAX(CASE WHEN EventId IN (6,7,13) THEN access_time END)
FROM Groupings g
GROUP BY
  ID,
  GroupId;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60ef5880e6df2ef1e959dd8387bf7df9)

Comment: Thanks this helped, but i wrote something similar. I will post my version of answer tomorrow. You are right, this is a gaps and islands problem.